# Why is MaybeChannelBound callable?

Tags: python

The Queue class in the python kombu library inherits from MaybeChannelBound, which in turn implements the **call** method (making it callable). The **call**() method itself is a thin wrapper around the bind() method.

It is not clear why this was done, as calling the bind() method seems (to my simple mind, at least) to be clearer and more descriptive of the intent of the function.

Why would somebody use the **call**() method in a situation like this?

Comment: To fulfill an Interface contract, perhaps?

Comment: The offending check-in doesn't have any reasoning so I'll assume for brevity. [link](https://github.com/ask/kombu/commit/3149a84d184e8843a27f3ad90bcb36b2beffdab8)

Comment: There's not enough information for this question to be answerable.  Any attempt to do so would most certainly involve examining the source code, which you haven't provided.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Please accept my apologies. The MaybeChannelBound object is defined here: https://github.com/ask/kombu/blob/master/kombu/abstract.py, whilst it's subclass, Queue, is defined here: https://github.com/ask/kombu/blob/master/kombu/entity.py. I am asking the question to gain some reassurance that I am not totally missing some fundamental idiom or design pattern. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

William,

I wrote the code, so I guess I should give an answer ;)

`MaybeChannelBound` is a common base class for `Exchange` and `Queue`,
because they both have the same semantics (terrible name, as so often happens
when one tries to use inheritance...)

The `__call__` was an API decision, so:

```
queue(channel)
```

returns a queue that is bound to a channel so that you can do operations
on it. I simply thought the call looked better in the API, I don't remember
exactly why I included the .bind method too, but I can guess that

- If someone wanted to create a subclass of this, then overriding
  a `bind` operation would seem neater than using `__call__`.
- When duck-typing it would be rather useless to check for `__call__` (callable),
  and `.bind` could be used for this purpose.

In recent Kombu you rarely have to bind the channels yourself, e.g.
when publishing a message you now send a list of entities to declare
to `Producer.publish` instead (and declarations are cached too):

```
producer = Producer(connection)
producer.publish(message, retry=True, declare=[queue])
```

where you previously would have to write:

```
with connection.channel() as channel:
    queue(channel).declare()
    producer.publish(message)
```

There isn't always any universally good reason for everything I do though,
sometimes I do things just because it is a practice of mine.
Sometimes those practices turns out the useful, other times
they just end up being useless boilerplate.